# is it safe to delete Hyperledger fabric Orderer logs?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, docker-logs

i see that my docker logs file is 67GB , if i truncate the docker logs file. will it effect my network ?
how i am doing it is by typing

```
sudo su
cd /var/lib/docker/containers/b390ca8178f28de33b702053cde84e7aba033d83a29a53777d601e2b5
echo -n "" > /home/ubuntu/b390ca8178f28de33b702053cde84e7aba033d83a29a53777d601e2b5aa18472-json.log
```

will it affect my network ? or is it safe to truncate the log files ? i know it's silly but still asking because it's hyperledger fabric based network.

Comment: It will not affect your system. I suggest you should resort to "Error" mode for all container so that you don't get low level log information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is safe to truncate the logs. We have a log rotation policy for a month. I zip the previous month's logs and dump them in a folder in case they are required for review.

I have a script which is run using a cronjob on the first day of every month.

```
#!/bin/bash

con=$(docker ps --format="{{.ID}}" --no-trunc)
containers=($con)
logdate=$(date "+%d-%b-%y-%H-%M")
for container in "${containers[@]}"
do
    name=$(docker inspect --format="{{.Name}}" ${container})
    sourcePath="/var/lib/docker/containers/${container}/${container}-json.log"
    destPath="/logstore/${name}-${logdate}.tar.gz"
    tar -cvzf ${destPath} ${sourcePath}
    echo "" > ${sourcePath}
done
```